# How to bold a specific substring in a string of xml node using XSLT while transforming into HTML

Tags: xml, xslt

I have to render a certain substring in the string of a XML node bold and change the color in html file while transforming a XML file using XSLT. I am using Vi sual studio 12.0 and not able to use XSLT 2.0 features like tokenize(),analyze-string() etc and I am new to XSLT.

The following is the XMLNode:

```
<LogMsg>
   Not able to do the given task as expected because of this **{reason}**.Please verify it.
</Logmsg>
```

I have to show the message present in flower braces in bold and red color while rendering in HTML.

The below is the part of XSLT code used in our application:

```
<xsl:for-each select="./LogMsg">                
   <pre>    
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>                         
   </pre>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Any help in this regards is very much thankful.

Regards,
Nagasree.

Comment: Will there always be exactly one such substring?

Answer (score 0):

If

1. the value of LogMsg is always a string (no child elements), and
2. there is always exactly one part of the string that must be colored reed and wrapped in braces, and
3. the part that must be colored red and wrapped in braces is always preceded by `**(` and followed by `)**`,

then it's straightforward to isolate the relevant part of the string:

```
<xsl:template match="LogMsg">
  <xsl:variable name="s1" select="substring-before(.,'**(')"/>
  <xsl:variable name="s2" 
      select="substring-before(substring-after(.,'**('),')**')"/>
  <xsl:variable name="s3" select="substring-after(.,')**')"/>
  <pre>
    <xsl:value-of select="$s1"
    /><xsl:text>**(</xsl:text
    ><b style="color: red;"
    ><xsl:value-of select="$s2"
    /><xsl:text>)**</xsl:text
    ><xsl:value-of select="$s3"/>
  </pre>
</xsl:template>
```

If the `**(` and `)**` are not present in the input, but the LogMsg always begins with "Not able to do the given task as expected because of this " and ends with ".Please verify it.", then it's equally simple to isolate the middle part of the message, using substring-before() and substring-after().  I'll leave the details as an exercise for the reader.

If neither of those sets of assumptions hold, then your question may need clarification.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Yes the assumptions hold as per my requirement. I tried what you have suggested and there are some errors while executing,I fixed them and I got the output as follows :

    "Not able to do the given task as expected because of this **()**  ".
 
The message does not contain the message which is to be in red color and message after that.Message in $s2 and $s3 is not written in the HTML.

Comment: Input of the form shown, run through the template I showed, cannot possibly produce the output you describe; there is a mismatch somewhere.  If you provide a minimum working example that illustrates the problem, it becomes possible to see what the difficulty is.  If you don't, then no one can do any more than guess.   There is good advice on asking effective questions in the [SO help files](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  and in Eric Raymond and Rick Moen's essay [How to ask questions the smart way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).